# GetString from Byte[] producing different after sending through socket

Tags: c#, sockets

So I am using C# sockets to send a string from one process to another.  I send the string using a byte array.  When I use GetString(Byte[]) in each process during debugging I get different results when the values in the Byte array are exactly the same from the point of the debugger.  In the process I send the string with the socket I get the same string back when using GetString().  However I get back gibberish after receiving the data on the other size.

To send the string I use:

```
        String strToSend = "This is just a test";
        Byte[] stringBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToSend);
        Int32 stringSize = stringBytes.Length;
        Int32 messageLengthInBytes = sizeof(Byte) + sizeof(Int32) + sizeof(Int32) + stringSize;

        Byte[] message = new Byte[messageLengthInBytes];
        message[0] = (Byte)MessageType.SendString;

        unsafe
        {
            Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)(Int32*)&messageLengthInBytes, message, 1, sizeof(Int32));
            Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)(Int32*)&stringSize, message, 5, sizeof(Int32));
            GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(stringBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)(Int32*)&pointer, message, 9, stringSize);
            pinnedArray.Free();
        }

        this.connection.SendMessage(message);
```

To receive the string in the other process I use:

```
                messageType = (MessageType)data[dataOffset];
                Debug.WriteLine(messageType.ToString());
                dataOffset++;

                Marshal.Copy(data, dataOffset, (IntPtr)(Int32*)&messageLengthInBytes, sizeOfInt32);
                dataOffset += sizeOfInt32;
                    Int32 stringSize = 0;
                    Marshal.Copy(data, dataOffset, (IntPtr)(Int32*)&stringSize, sizeOfInt32);
                    dataOffset += sizeOfInt32;
                    byte[] stringBytes = new byte[stringSize];
                    Array.Copy(data,dataOffset,stringBytes,0,stringSize);
                    dataOffset += stringSize;
                    String recievedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringBytes);
```

I get back gibberish that looks like, "h�z\0\0\0\0� \0\0\0\0\0��z".

I am sure that I have no offset problems when using the Marshal.Copy().  As I mentioned if I compare the integer values in each Byte[] in Visual Studio debugger they have the same values!  I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Why do you use `ASCII.GetBytes()` when sending, but `UTF8.GetString()` when receiving? Also I'd rather use BinaryReader/Writer than Marshal.Copy for handling the data, but that's me.

Comment: The code that is sending and receiving is missing. Also, this mess of data movement is indecipherable. Please simplify!

Comment: I left out my send and receive methods because I believe they are out of the scope of the issue and would add additional information to sift through.  I can send/receive Int32 and Doubles without problems.

Answer (score -1):

You're using ASCII.GetBytes() when sending, but UTF8.GetString() when you decode the recieved byte[].

Comment: True, but doesn't matter if the chars actually are in the safe ASCII set.

Comment: Good find.  I was messing with the encoding type and forgot to change back.  If both are ASCII or UTF8 I get similar results.

Comment: @JaredBolin what do you mean by "similar results"? For your test string both encodings result in the same bytes being emitted and decoded. This cannot be the root cause of your problems.